# Importing ExtensionAttribute via CSV with Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, import

I am trying to populate the attribute ExtensionAttribute7 with a CSV file. The CSV file has two columns: samAccountName and ExtensionAttribute7

I import the Active Directory module and have been trying this script:

```
Import-Csv C:\sam-eid.csv | ForEach-Object {
Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute7=$._ExtensionAttribute7}}
```

This is the error return I am getting:

$._ExtensionAttribute7 : The term '$._ExtensionAttribute7' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:2 char:62
+ ... mAccountName -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute7= $._ExtensionAttribute7}}
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($._ExtensionAttribute7:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any ideas? I've tried -Add instead of -Replace to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Import-Csv C:\sam-eid.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute7=$_.ExtensionAttribute7} }
```

You may have a syntax issue `$._` versus `$_.`

Comment: for some weird reason, the _ is not showing in the answer, even though it is there
Import-Csv C:\sam-eid.csv | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute7=$_.ExtensionAttribute7}}

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/help/formatting

Comment: The syntax was the issue. One of those situations where a fresh set of eyes makes all the difference in the world. Thank you!